# Is starting with a と a typo? Is ending with a し a typo?

Tags: grammar, quotes

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between me and my language partner.

> 「ささやく」についてですが、この動詞は、自動詞と他動詞、両方の使い方ができます。
>
> 「大蒜の神さまです」 と彼女はうやうやしくささやいた。
>   **と**他動詞として使うこともできます**し**、
>
> 「大蒜の神さまです」 と彼女はささやくように言った。
>   **のように、**自動詞として「ように」とつなげて使うこともできます。
>   （「ように」 については、あとで説明します）

The parts in bold are the ones which I'm not quite sure wether they were intended. 
1) I have no idea what the first と is supposed to do there. Really nothing.
2) できますし。I guess it could be し making the verb chuushi form, but I don't see how this would lead to a meaningful sentence combined with 「大蒜の神さまです」 と彼女はささやくように言った。
3) のように confused me at first, but I guess it is a casual way to say that she is going to say something about ように. "About ように" I guess is what shall be expressed by that?

Comment: Just a reminder: Please don't post answers in the comments section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no typo. You need to notice there is one big sentence with two embedded (or in-lined) example sentences. An English equivalent is something like this.

> As for ささやく, there are both intransitive and transitive usages.
>
> You can use it as a transitive verb ***like***:
>
> > 「大蒜の神さまです」 と彼女はうやうやしくささやいた。
>
> ***...and*** you can also use it as an intransitive verb that is followed by ように, ***like***:
>
> > 「大蒜の神さまです」 と彼女はささやくように言った。

1. This と is a simple quotative particle. The quoted part is the first example sentence right before it.
2. This し is a way to [connect two verbs](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-japanese-grammar-33/) in a sentence. Note that the sentence does not end at this point because the punctuation mark right after it is a comma (`、`). As you can see, colon (`:`) and ellipsis (`...`) are commonly used for this purpose in English.
3. This の here is a simple connecting particle that relates two nouns. The first "noun" is the second example sentence right before it.